# Browse dialog for custom server control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a custom server control that inherits from Hyperlink. The output html after control is rendered is a nice looking css button with an icon.
For the icon I have a string property.

What i would like to do is on the source code to open "browse file dialog" for the icon  similar to NavigateUrl property dialog see screen below

[image]

How this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the  [`UrlPropertyAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.urlpropertyattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).